# How to change colors in HTML

Tags: html, web, background-color

I am currently working on making a website using HTML5, but I am having trouble adding a background color. Here is what I tried: head bgcolor = #4169E1 (with the <>) and the same with a semicolon at the end.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<head>` tag dosen't takes `bgcolor` attribute. Try with `<body>` tag

Comment: The `bgcolor` attribute is obsolete and shouldn't be used. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html

Comment: @Litsabber_Dudeguy, please include examples of your code so everyone can see what you're working with

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a background color to body use

```
body {
  background-color : #your color goes here.
}
```

if you want to be universal , you can use

```
body *{
  background-color: #your color goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using inline styling?

```
<body style="background-color:red;">
</body>
```

Comment: This will work, but it is much better practice to set the value of the background-color attribute in a separate css file.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit with HTML (inline) or CSS:

**HTML**

```
<body> 
 <p style="color:red;">This text will be red</p>
<body>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  color:red;
}
```

`color` lets you edit words color.
`background-color` lets you highlight the text or words.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put bgcolor="#4169E1" in your body tag, not head. Like this:

```html
<body bgcolor="#4169E1">
</body>
```

Hope this helps!